# Elementary transformations of the set of vectors with respect to which the linear span is invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $L$ denote a linear space. Let $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n \in L$. Observe that

$span\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\} = span\{x_2,x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$

This motivates the following question: under what operations with $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ the $span\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ remains unchanged, i.e. is invariant?

Observe that $span\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}=span\{x_1 + x_2,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$

Definition. We say that $\{y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n\}$ is obtained from $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ using elementary operations and write $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}∼\{y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n\}$ if one of the following holds:

(summation) $y_i=x_i+x_j$ for some $i$ and $j$, and $y_k=x_k$ for $k\neq i$, or

(multiplication with a nonzero number) $y_i=\alpha x_i$ for some $i$ and some number $\alpha \neq 0$, and $y_k=x_k$ for $k\neq i$, or

(interchanging two vectors) $y_i = x_j$, $y_j=x_i$ for some $i$ and $j$, and $y_k=x_k$ for $k\neq i$, or

$\{y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n\}$ is obtained from $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ using finitely many steps 1, 2 or 3.

So my question is: what is this condition  $y_k=x_k$ for $k\neq i$ and why is it needed?

Comment: $y_k = x_k$ means the vector is unchanged. Example, $\{1,2,3\}$ becomes $\{3,2,1\}$, then $2$ is in this $y_k = x_k$ case.

Comment: @xbh under one step always exist the unchanged vector, yes?

Comment: Yes. The 3rd kind of step only change 2 vectors and leave others unaltered.

Comment: @xbh but this condition is also written in clauses 1 and 2. And in the same place, we can consider a singleton set of vectors

Comment: Well i think clause 3 should be $y_k = x_k$ when $k \neq i, k\neq j$. If only a singleton, then the clause 3 is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree with the first part of xbh's comment above: When interchanging two, all others stay the same, not just all but *one* of them getting switched [as you had it in your version of interchange]